# How to find duplicates in a dynamic list of lists in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<List<string>>` in C# - the number of items in the parent list will vary - there could be 1 or there could be 5. I need to know if there are any duplicates when considering all values in the same position in all lists.

This is vary similar to a database unique constraint on a composite key where you cant have duplicates. Each List contains all of the values from the data in the table.

For example if I have the following structure (but each one can have just 1 column or more):

```
Product    Color    Size
Tshirt     Blue     S
Tshirt     Blue     M
Tshirt     Blue     L
Tshirt     Blue     S <-- this is a duplicate
Tshirt     Red      S
```

This would be

```
var items = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", },
    new List<string>() { "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", },
    new List<string>() { "S", "M", "L", "S", "S", },
};
```

And I would need to detect the fact that there are duplicates and print the duplicates as

```
Duplicate: Tshirt, Blue, S
```

Note: finding a duplicate in a single list as addressed in the referenced 'duplicate' is easy, and finding duplicates if the list is static is tackleable, but this is different in that the size is completely unknown. It could really be a `List<List<string>>` that has 0 elements, 1 or more.

Comment: Why do you have a `List<List<string>>`? That is just bizarre and makes what you want to do more difficult.

Comment: Please also confirm for me that I've validly transformed your data in C# code.

Comment: @IanKemp - It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the referenced question is on a single list, and the number of columns doesnt dynamically change.

Comment: @IanKemp Would you mind pointing me to the exact dupe that addresses the List having a dynamic number of items. A List<> is easy to find duplicates in. A List<List<>> where the inner number varies is not addressed.

Comment: @colosso not a duplicate bud, love how you get 2 upvotes by posting something similar but not even close

Comment: @esac - What did you assume that I assumed?

Comment: @Enigmativity ha! I think I combined comments, apologies!

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, the translated code is correct.

Comment: Shorter path should be  make it anything else than list of list. My weridest idea would be some string concatenation by "column"  compare the result string. With a good enought separator it should be enought.

Comment: I could definitely take the inner lists and concatenate them together, but the issue is the separator as you mentioned - i have no guarantee on the format of this data.

Comment: @esac - you have not indicated yet why this is in such a crazy format. Do you know how to write a class?

Comment: @HenkHolterman unfortunately I do not always have the privilege of working with component coders and to just get my job done requires using what they give me. I get a List<List<string>>. The number of items in both lists is unknown and could be 0 or more. Essentially I get 'here is all of the data that cannot contain duplicates'.

Comment: Well, write a class Product, decode your input first and then find the duplicates. Stop the madness.

Comment: @HenkHolterman so what data structure would you recommend to use for a List<List<string>> where the number of elements of both are unknown and have no defined types? And even if I could, my only need with this is to determine if there are duplicates, I do not need to do anything more with it, so is it worth the effort?

Comment: When it is that dynamic then a class is not applicable. I can still see lots of more attractive ways to  store it, like a `List<dynamic>`. But either way, I would split it into a refactoring of the data and then a (simple) find the duplicates. You have rows and columns inverted, it will keep tripping people up. Testers, maintainers, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
var items = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", "Tshirt", },
    new List<string>() { "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Red", },
    new List<string>() { "S", "M", "L", "S", "S", },
};

var duplicates =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, items.First().Count)
        .Select(x => new { Product = items[0][x], Color = items[1][x], Size = items[2][x], })
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1).Take(1))
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: duplicates]

---

Given the need to handle a variable number of inner lists here's how to do it:

```
var duplicates =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, items.First().Count)
        .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(0, items.Count).Select(y => items[y][x]).ToArray())
        .GroupBy(x => String.Join("|", x))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1).Take(1))
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: duplicates2]

---

Here's a lazy version that doesn't use `Count`:

```
var duplicates =
    items
        .Select(xs => xs.Select(y => Enumerable.Repeat(y, 1)))
        .Aggregate((z0s, z1s) => z0s.Zip(z1s, (z0, z1) => z0.Concat(z1)))
        .GroupBy(ws => String.Join("|", ws))
        .SelectMany(gws => gws.Skip(1).Take(1));
```

Comment: I can try it, but I immediately notice that you have the length of the items array hardcoded in the Select statement. The List<List<string>> I am getting may be 1 element that I need to detect duplicates in or 2 or 3 or 5, and they arent always 'product/size/color', what they are is unknown to me, I just need to know if there are duplicates.

Comment: @esac - I haven't hard-coded the length - I've used `items.First().Count`. But you're saying that the number of `List<string>` is variable in the `List<List<string>>` so I can't use `new { Product = items[0][x], Color = items[1][x], Size = items[2][x], }`, right?

Comment: correct, the inner and outer lists both vary in the number of items. Just woke up and trying your suggestion now!

Comment: Your answer(s) work great, if you feel kind I also have a version I am working on where it is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is the column name, and the values is the List<string> - the end result needs to be a `List` of duplicates where each value is an anonymous class with the keys as the names and the values being the duplicate values.

Comment: @esac - I'm kind, but you'd need to ask a new question AND show that it is not a duplicate of this one. Put a link here when you post it.

Comment: That's ok, I had enough lambasting of people telling me that this one is a duplicate that I don't want to go over it again to suggest the subtle difference of Dictionary vs List.

Comment: @esac - Just try replacing the `List<List<string>>` with your `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and see what the compiler says. It's then just a refactoring exercise.

Comment: On a side note, what tool did you use to get that output? I tried linqpad, but it only put out enumerable's in the results, not the actual data.

Comment: @esac - It was LINQPad. I don't know what you mean about "put out enumerable's"?

Comment: nevermind i had it set to results to grid not rich text

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Zip()` and `Aggregate()` LINQ methods to find duplicates in a `List<List<string>>` (or even `List<List<object>>`):

```
string separator = ";%;*;%;";   // Pick a string that's very unlikely to appear in results

var duplicates = items.Aggregate((currentList, nextList) =>
                            currentList.Zip(nextList, (currentListItem, nextListItem) =>
                                $"{currentListItem}{separator}{nextListItem}").ToList())
                      .GroupBy(item => item).Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                      .Select(item => item.Key.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                            .ToList())
                      .ToList();
```

The [Aggregate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2) method will effectively loop through the outer list, considering 2 inner lists at a time; these lists can then be [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)ped together, item by item, to produce a new `IEnumerable<string>`; the `ToList()` call is necessary, as this new `IEnumerable<string>` becomes the next input into `Aggregate()` method, and must be in the same format as the next `List<string>`

Once all inner `List<string>` have been zipped into a new `IEnumerable<string>`, where the items are concatenated together with a separator (very important to have the separator, to avoid false positives on duplicate matching, as `"aa" + "abb" == "aaa" + "bb"`), you can simply `GroupBy()` the items, and find any group containing more than 1 item.

Finally, the last `Select()` converts the result back to `List<List<string>>` format, for easy comparison with original data.

This solution is fully LINQ (you can even hard-code the `string separator` directly into the query), and works for any number of inner lists (including only 1 list).